# How to pass lastest information to event handler dynamcally

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

How can I pass `leaveDetails` passed to the `setLeaveDetails` function to event handlers so that I do not have to add or remove events to `leaveAccept` or `leaveDecline` button again and again inside the `setLeavesDetails` function?
Can I use a global variable like `currentLeaveDetails` so I can get it from there or anything else I have to do?

**My html**

```html
<div id="leaveDetailsBox">
                <div class="smallHeading" id="leaverSeekerHeading">
                  leave request details
                </div>
                <div class="leaveRequestInformation">
                  <div class="SingleInfo">
                    <p class="infoTitle">leave seeker name</p>
                    <p class="infoDescription" id="leaveSeekerName"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="SingleInfo">
                    <p class="infoTitle">no. of days</p>
                    <p class="infoDescription" id="noOfDaysOfLeave"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="SingleInfo">
                    <p class="infoTitle">status</p>
                    <p class="infoDescription" id="leaveStatus">
                      pending
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="SingleInfo">
                    <p class="infoTitle">reason</p>
                    <p class="infoDescription" id="leaveReason">
                      Amritpal Singh sidhu
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="SingleInfo d-none">
                    <p class="infoTitle">leave Decline reason</p>
                    <p class="infoDescription" id="leaveDeclineReason"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="action" id="leaveRequestAction">
                    <button id="acceptBtn">approve</button>
                    <button id="declineBtn">Decline</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Here is JavaScript

```js
let leaveAcceptBtn = document.querySelector("#acceptBtn");
let leaveDeclineBtn = document.querySelector("#declineBtn");
function setLeavesDetails(leaveDetails) {
    leaverSeekerHeading.textContent = `${leaveDetails.leaveSeekerName}'s leave request details...`;
    leaveSeekerName.textContent = leaveDetails.leaveSeekerName;
    leaveReason.textContent = leaveDetails.leaveReason;
    leaveStatus.textContent = leaveDetails.status;
    leaveReason.textContent = leaveDetails.reason;
    if (leaveDetails.status !== "pending") {
        leaveRequestAction.classList.add("hide");
    } else {
        leaveRequestAction.classList.remove("hide");
    }



}
let declineHandler = (leaveDetails) => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure to decline leave?",
        icon: "question",
        input: "text",
        inputPlaceholeaveDetailser: "Enter leave reason(If Any)",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showCloseButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Decline",
        confirmButtonColor: "#eb5353",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        customClass: {
            title: "custom-title",
            icon: "custom-icon",
            confirmButton: "custom-confirm-button",
            cancelButton: "custom-cancel-button",
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.isConfirmed) {
            console.log(response.value);
            if (response.value.trim().length != 0 && response.value != " ") {
                updateLeaveStatus(leaveDetails._id, "declined", response.value);
            } else {
                updateLeaveStatus(leaveDetails._id, "declined");
            }
        }
    });
};
let acceptHandler = (leaveDetails) => {
    console.log("accept leave btn clicked");
    getLeaveSeekerEvents(leaveDetails);
};
leaveAcceptBtn.addEventListener("click", acceptHandler);
leaveDeclineBtn.addEventListener("click", declineHandler);
```

Comment: More or less what leave Detail will be worth is information about the click event and not what you want. If you want, you can modify an attribute of the label so that it contains the information you want to pass.  leaveAcceptBtn.param="Hello user";leaveAcceptBtn.addEventListener("click",function(e){console.log("The Param is "+e.target.param);});